# UIViewController hanging after viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, performance, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a simple workflow for my iOS 6 app :

```
UINavigationController -> loadingVC -(push)-> UITabBarController -> UIViewController(s)
```

I call the push via `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, called itself using an observer on `NSNotificationCenter`, but loading the root VC of the UITabBarController takes way too much time (~35 seconds).

Here is how I register the observer int he loadingVC :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadingDidComplete) name:@"dataDoneLoading" object:nil];
```

Then, my loadingVC calls some a method from my AppDelegate, which will proceed to some network stuff (fetch & parse XML files), and waits for a notification which will trigger :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"finishedLoading" sender:self];
```

And here is the console log I get on the loading of the root VC of the `UITabBarController` :

```
2013-05-06 16:28:19.720 *** [2289:19303] Notif sent
2013-05-06 16:28:19.720 *** [2289:19303] Notif received
2013-05-06 16:28:19.727 *** [2289:19303] viewDidLoad in         (some basic stuff)
2013-05-06 16:28:19.728 *** [2289:19303] viewDidLoad out
2013-05-06 16:28:19.729 *** [2289:19303] viewWillAppear         (NSLog only)
2013-05-06 16:28:54.475 *** [2289:19303] In numberOfSections    (datasource method of a UITableview, returns 0)
2013-05-06 16:28:54.832 *** [2289:12b03] viewDidAppear          (NSLog only)
```

As you can see, I have 35 seconds after `viewWillAppear` before the push actually happens. The app is hanging on the `loadingVC`, then pushes as usual.

All this happens in the simulator (I can't test on a physical device for the moment).

### What I tried :

• I use `SDSegmentedControl`, a subclass of `UISegmentedControl`, but I tried with the latter and the same problem happens.

• I removed my `UINavigationController` and replaced the push with a modal segue. It seems to work faster, but the UI is completely messed up: no animation during the segue (even though I set it to "yes"), the tab bar doesn't show text or icons on the segments until you tap them, my segmented control doesn't appear.

I can't seem to understand what's happening. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be performing the action in a background thread, which can easily happen depending on what the source of your notification is.  UIKit calls (like `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`) are not thread-safe and have unpredictable results when invoked on threads other than the main thread.

Try updating the beginning of your `-loadingDidComplete` method with the following:

```
-(void)loadingDidComplete {
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadingDidComplete)
                               withObject:nil
                            waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

    // ... rest of the method
}
```

Comment: Looks like this solves the problem. I thought it could not be this, as viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear were called, thanks for the quick fix !